# Union function type causes the function with fewer arguments to have all argument types as any

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I seem to have stumped myself on this one. I am trying to create a union type-alias of two functions. The compiler sees the types of all arguments of the function with fewer arguments as any.

```
interface Function1 {
    (param1: boolean, param2: number, param3: string): void;
}

interface Function2 {
    (param0: any, param1: boolean, param2: number, param3: string): void;
}

type FunctionUnion = Function1 | Function2;

const function1implemenattion: FunctionUnion = (param1, param2, param3) => {
    // param1 is any
    // param2 is any
    // param3 is any
}

const function2implementation: FunctionUnion = (param0, param1, param2, param3) => {
    // param0 is any
    // param1 is boolean
    // param2 is number
    // param3 is string
}
```

I would rather not do the following:

```
const function1implemenattion: FunctionUnion = (param1: boolean, param2: number, param3: string) => {
```

as that would counteract my usage of interfaces and make it more difficult to change types in the future.

How, if it all, could I accomplish this without sacrificing convenience or readability? I would like to avoid a signature such as this:

```
type FunctionUnion = (param0: any, param1: number | boolean, param2: number | string, param3?: string) => void
```

Thank you for taking the time to read & help solve my issue!

Comment: Why do you want a union of functions anyway?  [You can't call a union of functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).  Are you sure you don't want an intersection of functions instead, a.k.a. [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)?

Comment: @jcalz We're trying to accomplish something similar to [how express has multiple types of middleware](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L33-L52) although the way they use said functions is slightly different, as middleware is accepted as an argument while our functions are values on an object that is then passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this. You can, however, create an overloaded function like so.

```
interface YourFunction {
    (param1: boolean, param2: number, param3: string): void;
    (param0: any, param1: boolean, param2: number, param3: string): void;
}

const func: YourFunction = (p0, p1, p2, p3) => {}
```

While I previously thought overloaded functions would not solve my issue, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use types. 
Like that:

```
type Params = {
    parameter1: string | number,
    parameter2: string;
}

function test(...parameters: Params[]) {
    const var1= parameters[0].parameter1
    const var2 = parameters[0].parameter2
    // also you can see length of array size with parameters.length code
}
```

[The snipped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Params%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parameter1%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parameter2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(...parameters%3A%20Params%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20var1%3D%20parameters%5B0%5D.parameter1%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20var2%20%3D%20parameters%5B0%5D.parameter2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20also%20you%20can%20see%20length%20of%20array%20size%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)